# can find string if a variable batch (existing code needs editing)

Tags: string, batch-file, find

I have devised a way to remove a files name from its path and extension (replacing the files name with an asterisk).

However the out put file adds an extra space just before the closing quotation marks and i dont know why or how to fix this?

```
@echo off

SET EXTENT=%~x1
SET PATH=%~dp1

SET /P FILETYPE=

rem SET FILETYPE="%PATH%*%EXTENT%"

echo %FILETYPE%

pause

Type C:\HELLO.txt | findstr /I /V /C:%FILETYPE% >>C:\TEMP.txt

DEL /S/Q "C:\HELLO.txt"

ren "C:\TEMP.txt" "HELLO.txt"

DEL /s/q "C:\TEMP.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED

I changed this answer after gaining a better understanding of the question.

I think this code is close to what you want. You may need to play around with regexes for the `FINDSTR` command.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET EXT=%~x1

FINDSTR /I /V /C:%EXT% HELLO.TXT >>TEMP.TXT
DEL /Q HELLO.TXT
REN TEMP.TXT HELLO.TXT
```

Comment: nope tested that but it dosnt do anything, I have also noted that despite a pause the batch simply flashes and closes (tell tail sign that the programing is wrong)

Comment: If the `PAUSE` isn't happening, then you can't be sure the space before the redirection symbol isn't the problem. What happens if you open a command prompt and run the batch file from there (instead of double-clicking the file)?

Comment: thats a little hard considering the batch file is designed to have files droped on it (unless you know a way to drag and drop files ussing the command line)

Comment: okay managed a way to run it through the command line now it just hangs dosnt promt the expected "Press to continue" message

Comment: It's not hung, the `SET /P FILETYPE=` line is waiting for you type something in and press enter. You can change that line to `SET /P FILETYPE=Enter a filetype:` so you can see a prompt.

Comment: I just noticed this line `SET PATH=%~dp1`. This will overwrite the system `PATH` variable, so you probably want to change it to something like `SET MYPATH=%~dp1`

Comment: I found out what the problem is just not how to solve it the line i want to remove contains an astrix (take away the astrix it works) of cause it's a must to have the astrix. any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: I think your issue is because you are trying to use `*` as a wildcard but FINDSTR doesn't work like that. Look at the help for FINDSTR to see how to use regexes.